# using delete[] in main when new int [] was declared in a function

Tags: c++, arrays

My first job is this:

"The first function, readNumbers, is to read a set of 10 numbers from std::cin and use them to initialise a dynamically allocated array of int of length 10 (dynamic allocation is on the heap). The function must return a pointer to the array. You may assume that the input will be 10 integer values and nothing else."

which is fine, however i need to then:

"The main function for this problem must call your readNumbers function, then pass the new array to your printNumbers function and finally delete the array."

However i am unsure of how to handle the delete in main, when the new int [] has been declared in a function. here is the relevant parts of my code.

```
int *readNumbers(){
    int * numbers;
    numbers = new int [10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        int userinput;
        cin >> userinput;
        *(numbers+i) = userinput;
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

and

```
int main(){
    printNumbers(readNumbers(),10);

    delete[] numbers;

}
```

obviously the delete[] request in main is a syntax error, i am unsure of the solution.

Comment: It's not a syntax error. It just uses an undeclared variable.

Comment: Once you finish this, do yourself a good turn, and forget that the array form of `new` exists at all (except, possibly, after you've gotten your final grade, go tell your teacher to learn better things to teach).

Comment: Won't compile with a C compiler, don't tag it with C

Comment: Jerry, if youd like to point me in the direction of some more useful extra curricular learning id be down :).

Comment: Look at `std::vector` and `std::array`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `readNumbers()` to a variable, then you can delete it.

```
int main() {
    int *numbers = readNumbers();
    printNumbers(numbers, 10);
    delete[] numbers;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: youre a wizard, that was far too simple for me to have missed. cheers dude!